# Specify which .xcassets catalogue to use an image from in XIB

Tags: xcode, assets, target, workspace

If I had:

- two targets (`A` and `B`) in one Xcode project
- two different asset catalogues (`a.xcassets` and `b.xcassets`)

  - `a.xcassets` assigned to target `A` only
  - `b.xcassets` assigned to target `B` only
- `1.png` called `Image` in `a.xcassets` and `2.png` also called `Image` in `b.xcassets`

When building:

- `1.png` would end up in `Assets.car` in `A.app`
- `2.png` would end up in `Assets.car` in `B.app`

Both images could be referred to as `Image` in code or IB files with the correct image showing up in the respective build App.

**So far, so good. Now my problem:**

When adding a UIImageView to a `b.xib` belonging only to target `B` and referring to `Image` in that UIImageView, it doesn’t actually show `2.png` in the XIB display in Xcode but rather `1.png`. Xcode should know that `b.xib` belongs to target `B` and that it should look out for `Image` in `b.xcassets` rather than `a.xcassets` (as `a.xcassets` has no membership with target `B`).

What can I do to design my layout with the correct `Image` (`2.png`)?

Is there a way to tell Xcode a namespace or specify the asset catalogue to take `Image` from? I tried `b/Image` and `b.xcassets/Image`.

PS: the same goes for two projects (with a single target each) in one workspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, don’t do that. Don’t give the same name to image sets in different asset catalogs. As you have shown, it confuses Interface Builder.

You might be able to differentiate using asset catalog “folder” feature for name spacing but I have not found that to be totally reliable either.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If we can’t have the same name in two different catalogues then there is no point in allowing multiple catalogues per project (or even per workspace for that matter). I’d say that is a major oversight by Apple.

Comment: You can do it but it confuses Interface Builder. Your actual running app is fine, right?

Comment: Yes, the assets in the Apps (a.app and b.app) are all correct. It is just a pita to design the respective layouts in Interface Builder. I just hope(d) there is a way to make Xcode take the image from the correct catalogue (like the build toolchain knows it, so why shouldn’t Xcode?)

Comment: Well hope and a dime gets you a phone call. My answer stands. IB is old and crusty and doesn’t understand asset catalogs the way you do. File a bug report with Apple if this matters to you.